# C# Windows Form Application, button name with readline

Tags: c#, winforms, button, readline

I want to create button that is named by the user.

This is what I have (sorry I'm so bad at this but I am trying :D)

```
string 1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (1 = null)
    {
        Console.Write("Give Button's name");
        1= Console.ReadLine();
        button1.Name = 1;   
    }
}
```

I also want the button to open a file path selected by the user. Is there a way to do that?

(sorry for my stupid question and anything else... :D)

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: You cannot start a variable name with a numeric. Please use a proper variable name instead of `1`.

Comment: No this is only my trying, i asked this question because i dont know how can i do...

Comment: @waldorick It's hard to understand what you want. I guess you want to change button1.Text based on the user's input. and use that input to open a file??

Comment: also you are mixing between windows forms program and console program.

Comment: is it Console app or WinApp?

Comment: @DanielBahmani no... i want an input by the user for the button1.Text first. When it's complete i want an input from the user for a file path what the button open for click

Comment: @DanielBahmani it's a windows form apllication

Comment: @AmrElgarhy yes it's possible, i only want to learn the windows form

Comment: @asch it's ready now but the "rename" command is not okay yet :/ :D

Comment: you will need to watch at least introduction tutorials about windows forms and how to get input from users, may be you can use a textbox on the form or show a prompt message, ... many other ways...

Comment: yes i think :/ sorry for the stupid question and thanks the help for all :)

Comment: Thank you the answers guys, and thanks for the edit@ninja coder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on yr comments:
 1. Use a TextBox(called txtUserInput) to get the user's input
 2. Use OpenFileDialog to help user to choose a file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserInput.Text))
    {
        button1.Text = txtUserInput.Text;
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You chose: " + openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix Console Application input with Windows Forms input. You need to decide what you want. From the comments, it looks like you want a Windows Form Application so you will need some way to get user input like a text box.

On your form you will need to create a text box and give it a name like `tbxUserInput`. After that you can change you click method to do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = tbxUserInput.Text
}
```

One thing that was wrong was that you were assigning the Name property of the button and not the Text property. The text property is what is actually displayed on the button.

It may be a good idea to read some tutorials about Windows Forms.